# "fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource"

Tags: drush

drush throws an error

> "**Notice**:  Use of undefined constant STDERR - assumed 'STDERR'
>   in **/kunden/192766_10587/bin/drush/includes/drush.inc** on line
>   **1668**
>  
>  **Warning**:  fwrite(): supplied argument
>   is not a valid stream resource in
>   **/kunden/192766_10587/bin/drush/includes/output.inc** on line
>   **34**

What I did is the following. (I followed the instruction from the README.)

1. Cloned drush

   ```
   git clone --branch 7.x-5.x http://git.drupal.org/project/drush.git
   ```
2. Wrote into the ~/.bashrc

   ```
   export PATH="$PATH:~/bin/drush:/usr/local/bin"
   alias drush=~/bin/drush/drush.php
   ```
3. Refreshed the bashrc

   ```
   source ~/.bashrc
   ```
4. Set the 'drush' command executable:

   ```
    chmod u+x /path/to/drush/drush
   ```

Drush is working but it shows errors every time.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: If you solved your query consider posting the solution as an answer and approve it as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should not run drush.php directly.  It is preferable to define DRUSH_PHP, like this:

`export DRUSH_PHP='/usr/local/bin/php'`

Then you may continue to use the drush script as usual.  This is documented in the README.

Comment: I have the same problem, with your answer i can resolved this with drush, but for this way. 
`export COLUMNS
alias drush='/usr/local/bin/php ~/drush/drush.php --php=/usr/local/bin/php'
alias php='/usr/local/bin/php'`